# Open source projects in groovy?

Tags: groovy, open-source

I am a java programmer who recently took interest in groovy. I want to dabble further into the language as I enjoy programming in groovy. So, I am looking for projects to start with. I find many projects in C, C++ and java but not many in groovy.

I do not know where to start. Can you please suggest me some good open source projects in groovy, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is probably going to get closed as overly vague or off topic, but what sort of things are you looking for?

There's [Grails](https://github.com/grails/grails-core) of course as one example of Open source projects

Or of course, you could just look at [all the repositories on GitHub](https://github.com/languages/Groovy) with Groovy as their base language...